# JPA 2 Criteria API: filtering on a specific field in collections without static Metamodel

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

I have a JPA datamodel as following(a simplified version) and I would like to get demands having events between some given dates.

```
public class Demand {
 private Set<Event> events;
}

public class Event {
 private Date date;
}
```

I do get a Path reference to events attribute but I don't know how to express a between predicate based on the date attribute.

```
Path<Set<Evenement>> pathEvents = demand.<Set<Evenement>> get("events");
pathEvents.get("date")
```

throw "org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source" exception.
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to get refences to Event's attributes

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> c = cb.createTupleQuery();
Root<Demand> demandes = c.from(Demand.class);
Join<Demand, Evenement> joinEvent = d.join("events", JoinType.INNER);
```

I cant get path refences from the join object.

```
Path<DateTime> dateExpr = joinEvent.get("date");
```

Comment: I don't recall but I think it is supposed to be demandes variable.